# Condo in HOA building that has been disbanded

Tags: united-states, real-estate, home-owners-association

I found a listing for a property that is in a high rise building where the HOA has been disbanded.  This is the note from the listing:

> HOA is disbanded and HOA has past taxes.

What pitfalls are probable in such a situation?

Comment: One pitfall would be that you'd be on the hook for these past taxes...

Comment: If there's no HOA who's going to be responsible for maintenance expenses and utilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from what was mentioned already, the biggest risk is being unable to get a mortgage.  Even if you buy it as a cash transaction, you may have issues when you try to sell to someone else also needing a mortgage.  Banks will generally need to see lots of information from a HOA (such as an annual budget, master deed/by-laws, etc. depending on the bank) and will deny a loan based on things like that.